# Error: nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonMerge

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

i am configuring the ajax json function in the Spring MVC 3.0 Maven project and get the error message that "nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonProcessingException".
So, what should i do to configure the pom.xml to install the needed classes?

Any suggestions would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below dependencies to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
  <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Replace `${jackson.version}` with any version you want,or just add 2.x.xat top of your pom.xml

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! And it is OK now. But it is quite strange that these dependencies are not needed before I changed the new Apache 7 server. At that time I only use below dependencies to correctly use the Ajax json functionality:

Comment: <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>  
            <artifactId>jackson-core-lgpl</artifactId>  
            <version>1.8.1</version>  
</dependency> 
<dependency>  
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>  
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-lgpl</artifactId>  
            <version>1.8.1</version>  
</dependency>

Comment: Sometimes it happens because of version conflicts also..please upvote the answer too...thanks

Comment: since my reputation is less than 15, my upvoting to your answer had recorded but not shown publicly